# Saving an XML Feed in an InputStream into a local file in Android?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, fileoutputstream, local-files

I'm reading an XML feed from a web site, but, for performance reasons, I'd like to be able to read it into a local file on Android, so I can process it several times without incurring network delays and costs.

I'm reading the web file using the following code:

```
    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream instream = conn.getInputStream();
        return instream;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("downloadUrl", "4 - Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a "4 - Exception: null" message from downloadUrl(), which is screwing up my file saving code below:

```
    public Boolean copyStream(String feed, String file) {
    InputStream input_data = null;
    FileOutputStream output_data = null;

    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len = 0;

    int buffer_count = 0;

    try {
        input_data = downloadUrl(feed);
        output_data = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        while ((len = input_data.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output_data.write(buffer, 0, len);
            buffer_count++;
        }
        input_data.close();
        output_data.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("copyStream", "Error=" + e.getMessage() + ", feed=" + feed
                + ", file=" + file + ", buffer_count=" + buffer_count);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I can resolve the InputStream problem, will copyStream() send the XML text to a local file without permission errors?

Thanks in advance............Phil

---

greenapps,

This is the logcat, but it says little more than I'd already provided (replace 192.168.1.213 with 83.104.132.69 for an external URL):

```
06-19 08:05:04.414: I/downloadUrl(1108): 4 - Exception: null
06-19 08:05:04.414: E/copyStream(1108): Error=/summary.xml: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system), feed=http://192.168.1.213/cgi-bin/beerxml_a.cgi?beer_display=Summary&beer_country=*All*&beer_brewer=*All*&beer_type=*All*, file=summary.xml
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace/logcat. Permissions not needed for private internal memory.